# Return array of serialized data in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Symfony 4. I have 2 entites, `Cat` and `Dog`, which need to be serialized, then returned as a JSON response like this:

```
{
  'cats': // array of serialized cat data
  'dogs': // array of serialized dog data
}
```

This is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cat::class);
    $cats = $repository->findAll();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Dog::class);
    $dogs = $repository->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse([
        'cats' => $this->serializeData($cats, 'cats'),
        'dogs' => $this->serializeData($dogs, 'dogs'),
    ], 200);
}
```

And my `serializeData` method looks like this:

```
protected function serializeData($data, $group)
{
    return $this->json($data, $this->statusCode, [], [
        'groups' => [$group]
    ]);
}
```

Here's a bit of the `Cat` entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
[...]
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CatRepository")
 */
class Cat
{
    [...]
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("cats")
     */
    private $name;
    [...]
}
```

The problem: when hitting this endpoint, instead of the data I get:

```
{
    "cats": {
        "headers": {}
    },
    "dogs": {
        "headers": {}
    }
}
```

`headers` is not part of either entity.

EDIT:

What else I've tried:

```
public function index()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cat::class);
    $cats = $repository->findAll();
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Dog::class);
    $dogs = $repository->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse([
        'cats' => $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($cats, 'json', [
            'groups' => ['cats'],
        ])
        'dogs' => $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($dogs, 'json', [
            'groups' => ['dogs'],
        ])
    ], 200);
}
```

This sort of works but `new JsonResponse` serializes the already serialized cats and dogs. And of course if I replace `new JsonResponse` with `new Response` I get the error

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Symfony Serializer component:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/components/serializer.html

Comment: Thanks - in the edit to my question I've shown what happens when I use the serializer directly.

Answer (score 1):

well, method $this->json returns an JsonResponse so the whole stuff returns an JsonResponse(JsonResponse...) - [source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L122)

```
public function index()
{
...
    return $this->json(['cats' => $cats, 'dogs' => $dogs], 200, [], ['groups' => ['cats', 'dogs']]);
}
```

Comment: If I remove the `@group` annotations, I remove the functionality offered by `@group` annotations, which I have put in there because I need it.

Comment: well, so I think you need to combine it by yourself. look at the source code and you'll get how the serializer is used - just serialize $cats and $dogs. I'll try to update the post in cuple of minutes - but I can't check it

Comment: Thanks for persisting, I've edited my answer to show what happens when I follow your approach.

Comment: do you have some annotations within the action methos in the controller?

Comment: No, the `index` method only has a route annotation.

Comment: you can use array of groups in serializer - check the new version pls:)

Comment: I know, but for "reasons" I need to have specific groups only for specific entities. So I need the `Cat` entity to *only* have the `cats` group applied to it. If the `cats` AND the `dogs` groups are applied to it, chaos will result.

Comment: I don't want to waste any more of your time on this, I think my use case is a bit niche, and too long to explain in a single post. Thanks for your help!